# Django crontab not running permanently on google ubuntu instance

Tags: python-3.x, django, cron

I am using crontab in Django(3.1.8) on the google VM ubuntu instance.

```
###  settings.py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
          'django_cron',
          ...
]

CRONJOBS = [
    ('*/5 13-20 * * 1-5', 'app.cron.cron_function'),
    ('1 12 * * 1-5', 'app.cron.cron_function2'),
    ('*/1 13-20 * * 1-5', 'app.cron.cron_function3'),
    ('*/5 13-20 * * 1-5', 'app.cron.cron_function4'),
]

###   app/cron.py
def cron_function():
    something doing ...

def cron_function2():
    something doing ...

def cron_function3():
    something doing ...

def cron_function4():
    something doing ...
```

while I add crontab with `python manage.py crontab add`. so this cron job is run only once.
so how to run the cron jobs functions always.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are adding django_crontab to the list of installed apps is not correct.

INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django_crontab',
...
)